# JPA / Hibernate: Simple "find" results in console text character salad and application stucks

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

hope someone could help:

I try to do a simple find with Spring Boot 3 / JPA Jakarta / Hibernate 6.

If i do a simple "EntityManager.find" the application stuck.

[image]

This is the output of my unit tests.

I played around with the Entities and it seems, that they are to complex?

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "_MODELTYPE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class TestAbstract {
  // [... other variables, id etc.]
  /** multiple abstracts. */
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deepListAnchor", cascade = {})
  private Collection<TestDeepAbstract> someList;
  // more here...
}
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "_MODELTYPE")
public abstract class TestDeepAbstract {
  // ...
  @ManyToOne
  private TestAbstract deepListAnchor;
  // ...
}
```

If i remove all this abstract collections, it works fine. With Spring Boot 2.X and Hibernate 5 all was working perfect. Hope, that anyone has an idea, what i'm doing wrong.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Having a default persistence.xml with the Hibernate Provider:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="system"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
                <!-- all classes etc here -->
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The Test itself:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = emf.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = cb.createTupleQuery();
    Root<TestCustomerPerson> root = query.from(TestCustomerPerson.class);
    List<Selection<?>> selectFields = new ArrayList<Selection<?>>();
    selectFields.add(root.get("id").alias("id"));
    query.multiselect(selectFields);

    List<Predicate> exps = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    exps.add(cb.equal(root.get("firstname"), "hans"));
    exps.add(cb.equal(root.get("lastname"), "meister"));
    Predicate andClaus = cb.and(exps.toArray(new Predicate[0]));


    List<Predicate> exps1 = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    exps1.add(cb.equal(root.get("firstname"), "bob"));
    exps1.add(cb.equal(root.get("lastname"), "burger"));
    Predicate andClaus1 = cb.and(exps1.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

    
    List<Predicate> ober = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    ober.add(andClaus);
    ober.add(andClaus1);
    Predicate orClaus = cb.or(ober.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    
    query.where(orClaus);

    try (EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager()) {
      TypedQuery<Tuple> listQueryWithoutPagination = em.createQuery(query);

      List<Tuple> tupleResult = listQueryWithoutPagination.getResultList();
      assertEquals(2, tupleResult.size());
      
      TestCustomerPerson tcp = em.find(TestCustomerPerson.class, "1");
      assertNotNull(tcp);
    }
```

// EDIT: I build a test repository. Seems like a hibernate bug?
https://github.com/mertins-codamic/hibernate-3-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every association in your model uses `FetchType.EAGER` which results in a SQL query that has 2 million characters and the data structures behind the scenes to read that need to be built as well. Building the SQL and the data structures takes quite some time as you can imagine, so it is not stuck, but the program actually tries to process all of that. Eclipse just prints garbage when the string reaches a certain length I guess.

I'd say you are running into a situation that is described in the migration guide: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#fetch-circularity-determination

You just have way to many self referencing eager associations. You should seriously consider making all to-one associations `LAZY` by default and use entity graphs or join fetches to fetch the data only when needed.

Comment: That's it. I read the guide many times, but that was the thing i missed. I added fetch-type Lazy to all the "ToOne" associations as you described and it worked. Thank you very much.